# Conversion between px and dp unit

Tags: java, android, layoutparams, density-independent-pixel

I want to set `layout_marginTop` to 800px using `setLayoutParams()`. But I want know what would be this value in `dp` unit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `LayoutParams` expects pixel. You have to be more specific...

Comment: If you're trying to convert dip to px then here it is: `int px = (int) (dip * mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f)`. I still do not understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: main idea in questions is  convert pixels to dp.

I want to know 1dp = ?px in my screen.

Comment: 1 dip = `mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density`. So dip depends on the current device configuration. You should mention that in your question, so other people know what you're searching for.

Comment: Sorry I change question for people understanding in my question.

Comment: You were already given the answer, in the upvoted comments. The rest is basic arithmetic.

Comment: my screen 552x1024 I want to set margin top 800px. How many set dip in LayoutParams margin top

Comment: Sorry I change question for people understanding in my question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical [density](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density) of the display is given in the `DisplayMetrics` class, and can be retrieved with,

```
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density
```

Thus, to convert `dp` to `px`, you would do,

```
int density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int px = (int) (dp * density);
```

To convert `px` to `dp`, just perform the inverse operation,

```
int dp = px/density;
```